# Javascript stuck at function using XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

This is some code I wrote:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Home</title>
    <script src="js/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/login.js"></script>
    <script>
        isLoggedIn(value => {
            document.write('<p>' + value + '</p>')
        })
        document.write('hello')
    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

javascript code to check whether userid and token is not expired

```js
function isLoggedIn(callback) {
    if (Cookies.get('isLoggedIn') === 'true' && Cookies.get('userid') !== undefined && Cookies.get('token') !== undefined) {
        //check if userid and token are valid
        const request = new XMLHttpRequest()
        request.onreadystatechange= ()=>{
            if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
                callback(request.responseText)
            } else {
                //Cookies.remove('isLoggedIn')
                callback(request.responseText)
            }
        }
        request.open('GET', 'http://localhost:63343/Grades/login.php?'+"userid=" + Cookies.get('userid') + '&token=' + Cookies.get('token'), true)
        request.send()
    } else {
        callback(false)
    }
}
```

For some reason, the program never gets to print hello and is stuck forever at the function call before. The web page just keeps loading forever (longer than one hour) and prints {"msg":"valid"} twice which is the correct response but it should only be printed once and then continue. Does someone know how to fix this weird behavior?

Answer (score 0):

XMLHTTPRequest is asynchronous since HTTP requests take time to finish, try attaching a callback to the parameters of the function

Ex:

```js
function isLoggedIn(callback) {
    // ...
    const request = new XMLHttpRequest()

    request.onreadystatechange = () => {

        if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
            callback(JSON.parse(this.responseText)['msg'] === 'valid');
        } else {
            Cookies.remove('isLoggedIn');
            callback(false);
        }
    }
    // ...
}

// Then call the function passing a function as a parameter
isLoggedIn(value => {
    if (value) {
        // do stuff if logged in
    } else {
        // do stuff if not logged in
    }
})
```